# Ant not running all targets

Tags: ant, jenkins

I have the following ant file that is not running the targets "prepForDeployment" and "deployToStaging". This task is being run by Jenkins and I'm not getting any build errors when I look at the console output of the test.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <project name="deploy" default="runUnitTests" basedir=".">
    <description>
        Deploys to staging.
    </description>

    <target name="init">

        <taskdef name="mxunittask" classname="org.mxunit.ant.MXUnitAntTask" classpathref="project.classpath" />

        <!-- dump the properties -->
        <echoproperties prefix="test" />
    </target>

    <target name="clean" depends="init">
        <mkdir dir="${test.junitoutput}" />
    </target>

    <target name="runUnitTests" depends="init,prepForTests">
        <mkdir dir="${test.output.xml}/unit" />
        <runTestDirectory directoryName="." excludes=""/>
    </target>

    <target name="runAllTests" description="Make output directories and run the MXUnit task" depends="init,clean,runUnitTests">
        <!-- generate pretty reports -->
        <antcall target="junitreport" />
        <fail if="tests.bombed" message="Failing the build due to test failures"/>
    </target>


    <target name="junitreport" depends="init" description="Runs the report without running the tests">
        <junitreport todir="${test.junitoutput}">
            <fileset dir="${test.output.xml}">
                <include name="*.xml" />
            </fileset>
            <report format="frames" todir="${test.junitoutput}" />
        </junitreport>
    </target>

    <target name="prepForTests">
        <!-- just a bunch of replace tasks, runs OK -->
    </target>


    <target name="prepForDeployment" depends="init">

        <replace file="Application.cfc">
            <replacetoken>dbcreate="dropcreate"</replacetoken>
            <replacevalue>dbcreate="update"</replacevalue>
        </replace>

        <replace file="Application.cfc">
            <replacetoken>logSQL = true</replacetoken>
            <replacevalue>logSQL = false</replacevalue>
        </replace>

        <echo message="Prepping for deployment done." />
    </target>

    <target name="deployToStaging" depends="prepForDeployment">

        <sequential>
            <!--copy the files to a temp directory-->
            <copy todir="${staging}_temp" overwrite="true">
                <!-- -->
            </copy>

            <!-- delete applicaiton files on staging -->
            <delete quiet="true" includeemptydirs="true">
                <fileset dir="${staging}" />
            </delete>

            <!-- copy files from temp dir to application dir -->
            <copy todir="${staging}" overwrite="true">
                <fileset dir="${staging}_temp" />
            </copy>

            <!-- remove temp dir -->
            <delete quiet="true" includeemptydirs="true">
                <fileset dir="${staging}_temp" />
            </delete>
        </sequential>

        <echo message="The files have been copied to staging." />
    </target>

    <macrodef name="runTestDirectory">
        <attribute name="directoryName"/>
        <attribute name="excludes" default=""/>
        <sequential>
            <mxunittask server="${test.server}" port="${test.serverport}" defaultrunner="${test.runner}" outputdir="${test.output.xml}/@{directoryName}" verbose="true" failureproperty="tests.bombed" errorproperty="tests.bombed">
                <directory path="${test.dir.location}/@{directoryName}" recurse="true" packageName="${test.cfcpath}.@{directoryName}" componentPath="${test.cfcpath}.@{directoryName}" excludes="@{excludes}" />
            </mxunittask>
        </sequential>
    </macrodef>

</project>
```

Comment: Which targets do you call on the script? If none, only the default-target (runUnitTests) and it's dependencies (init,prepForTests) are executed.

Comment: I'm calling runUnitTests form Jenkins too.  How can I get the others to run as dependencies for runUnitTets but to execute after that completes w/o the <fail> triggering?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're not telling Jenkins to run the `prepForDeployment` and `deployToStaging` targets then it won't run them, just the same as when you run Ant on the command line.

If you want those targets to run, add them to the target list under your "Invoke Ant" build step.

Comment: OK, I think I'm getting it.  What if I want prepForDeployment to be dependent on "runUnitTests" completing and "deployToStaging" dependent on "prepForDeployment" completing.

Comment: Thanks, this worked.  I also noticed that my default was incorrect, it should have been "runAllTests" in which case I created a depends on "deployToStaging" which has a depends on "prepForDeployment".